# 'Discard All Changes' deleted my untracked files

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I had some untracked files in my *Xcode* project and while working on the project I wanted to discard all the changes that I had made. 
So I went to **Source Control > Discard All Changes** in *Xcode* (it seemed like such an easy option). But, to my surprise, *git* deleted all my untracked files.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: No it isn't the expected behavior.

Comment: Any idea why is it happening, then?

Comment: Are you sure the files were untracked?

Comment: Yes, I double checked them from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

`git` does have a command to remove untracked documents : `git clean -fd`.

If *XCode* triggered this git command when running **Discard all changes**, I'm afraid this is bad news.
If such is the case, you will have to turn to Time Machine or undelete utilities to try and recover your deleted files. You can also send a bug report to the *XCode* team ...

It would seem weird for an IDE to have such an easy way to massively remove files from the disk, though. Try to read the documentation to see if `git clean` was triggered, or if the files were moved in some sort of secret place by *XCode*, or something like that.

Comment: It moves them to the **Trash**.

Comment: Ok. So my comment seems off target.

Comment: I couldn't find anything regarding this in the documentation. I guess I'd have to send a bug report to Xcode team as you've suggested.